# Would it cost any extra performance if multiple invoke methods that are overload?

Tags: c#

Many times,and many situation,I saw that some codes,just throw the jobs,without thinking that how many methods the App will actually invoke.
For instance,I get an `Array` `a1`, and `a2`. and I am confirm that I will copy all of the elements from `a2` to `a1`. So there are many overload methods I can choose.
If i choose `Copy(Array sourceArray, Array destinationArray, int length)`,
the code itself ,however will pass the parameters to the

```
Copy(sourceArray, sourceArray.GetLowerBound(0), destinationArray, destinationArray.GetLowerBound(0), length, false);
```

So,would it save any performance if I call the second method directory instead of the first one?

Comment: You shouldn't care about that at all. It will most likely be optimized by jitter anyway.

Comment: You're copying an array and you're worried about the overhead of a function call?  Do you know if the call was inlined?  Did you test both methods?

Comment: Thanks for you all,and you two have got the point.Actually,I just came up an ideal and did not think about the inlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the phrasing of your question (that is "*any* extra") the answer is **yes** (if you look with adequate *belligerence*).

If the question was "is there *any meaningful* extra cost", the answer is **no**.

You should focus on your algorithm and remember that "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - [Knuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)